# Iterating to a List of objects and adding to a HashMap after calculating the average

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I need to create a function

```
Map<Category, Double> averagePricePerCategory
```

that receives a `List<Buildings> buildings` as a parameter of objects that have:

```
private int price;
private String neighborhood;
private Category category;
```

I need to get the price for each of them, calculate the average and return a Map with their respective category and its average price.
I'm really struggling to understand how I can do this.

So far I'm stuck at what to do next and how it should like.

```
static Map<Category, Double> averagePricePerCategory(List<Building> buildings) {
    Map<String, Double> averagePriceCategory = new HashMap<>();
    Category x = buildings.get(0).getCategory();
    if(buildings.isEmpty()){
        return new HashMap<>();
    }else{
        for(Building b: buildings){

        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: 1. You don't need to special-case `buildings` being empty: if you write it "normally" that will logically follow. 2. why return `null`? Is that ever an appropriate return value? What could you return instead (ignoring that the rest of the method isn't fully written for now). 3. How would you do it "manually" on paper? What would you do to get the averages?

Answer (score 2):

If I got the point of your question correct, using stream api you could use something like this:

```
static Map<Category, Double> averagePricePerCategory(List<Building> buildings) {
        return buildings.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Building::getCategory, Collectors.averagingDouble(Building::getPrice)));
    }
```

You can find more examples about grouping with stream api here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector

Comment: This worked like a charm but I think I need to actually get the hang of Streams as I haven't learned them yet.
Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To make a performant average solution from a list of numeric values, keep two variables : the sum of them, the count of them, then `avg = sum/count`

As we need to do it for each Category, we need a grouping step, an idea could be to make lists of prices for each Category, but that will be memory consuming, so we're sticking to the first idea of `sum` and `count`, for each Category

```
static Map<Category, Double> averagePricePerCategory(List<Building> buildings) {
    Map<Category, Double> sumPriceCategory = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Category, Integer> countPriceCategory = new HashMap<>();

    for (Building building : buildings) {
        sumPriceCategory.merge(building.getCategory(), building.getPrice(), Double::sum);
        countPriceCategory.merge(building.getCategory(), 1, Integer::sum);
    }

    Map<Category, Double> avgPriceCategory = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<Category, Double> entry : sumPriceCategory.entrySet()) {
        avgPriceCategory.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() / countPriceCategory.get(entry.getKey()));
    }
    return avgPriceCategory;
}
```

---

```
List<Building> buildings = List.of(
        new Building(10, new Category("house")), new Building(20, new Category("house")),
        new Building(30, new Category("house")), new Building(40, new Category("house")),
        new Building(40, new Category("school")), new Building(400, new Category("school"))
);
System.out.println(averagePricePerCategory(buildings)); // {school=220.0, house=25.0}
```